# Is there a way to automatically pseudo-randomize a MAC address?

Tags: networking, wireless, android

It is possible to track a person by the unique MAC address of their wireless card. For Android devices, there's an app called [Pry-Fi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.pryfi&hl=en) that, among other things, constantly pseudo-randomizes one's MAC address, "following a pattern that still makes the trackers think you are a real person, but they will not encounter your MAC address again"

Is there a similar tool for Ubuntu, or, if there isn't, what's the next best thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such a tool and it's called MACCHANGER. It is available by default in the Ubuntu repos, so you can just install with

```
sudo apt-get install macchanger
```

See [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses#Install_MACCHANGER) of the Ubuntu wiki, also for some caveats.

Comment: Installed it, thanks. How do I free up the network interface so that I can change the MAC address? It says '`Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy`', even with `sudo` and disconnected from Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I have also added a startup script, as instructed in the wiki, but on reboot `sudo macchanger --show  wlan1` there's no difference (Current MAC equals Permanent MAC). How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes, I guess this **is** the answer; the fact that wireless device is busy or `macchanger` doesn't actually change MAC on my computer should be a separate question.

Comment: @Nemo: by the way, disconnecting from the Wi-Fi network may not be enough, see for instance https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162167